# Weird Facebooker Plugin & Pushion Passenger ModRails Production Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, facebooker

I have an application (Rails 2.3.5) that I'm deploying to production Linux/Apache server using the latest Phushion Passenger/Apache Module 2.2.11 version. After deploying my original application, it returns a 500 error with no logging to production log.

So I created a minimal test rails application, with some active record calls to the database to print out a list of objects to the home controller/my index page. I also cleared out all plugins. That works fine in the production environment. Then I one by one introduced each plugin that I'm using one at a time.

Every plugin works fine EXCEPT facebooker. Every time I load the facebooker plugin into my app/vendor/plugins directory (via script git etc) my test application break (500 error - no error logging). Everytime I remove the facebooker plugin my test application works.

Has anyone seen this before/ have any solutions? I saw this solution but [didn't see it in the facebooker code.](http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=220#c6)

Comment: in the facebooker init.rb file this line is causing the 500 error for my app.

"require ‘facebooker/rails/extensions/rack_setup’ if Rails.version > ‘2.3’"

still hunting this down…

Comment: I got my application working by commenting out that line about rack_setup but I'm still getting odd error like this in the production log. I think its related:

/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Sun Apr 18 18:49:10 -0400 2010
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  undefined method `rewind' for #<UNIXSocket:0xb7210e00>
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/request.rb:142:in `POST'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:15:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/ge

Answer (score 0):

Did you add Facebook credentials for production environment?